# How can I get an environment variable from Xcode in my app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have installed the Xcode plugin for XcodeColors from robbie hanson.
(see https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors)

If I test it in a playground

```
let dict = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment
let env = dict["XcodeColors"] as? String
```

**env** would be "YES".

But, if I use the same code in my app, **env** would be nil, because the app is running on their own process.

Because I would print out colored text with specific esc sequences only if the plugin is installed, I want get the information about the Xcode env var.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you discovered a solution?

Answer (score 13):

Edit your scheme -> Select the "Run" section -> Select "Arguments" tab -> Add the environment variable.

Be careful, environment variables are not set if you run the app without XCode.

Comment: thanks, this approach I used too. But, if I share my source to another developer, I must explain what is to do, having XcodeColors installed or not. I want do it from my app automatically.

Comment: Note that Xcode is not run by BASH, so the environment defined here, only lived within Xcode.

Comment: See also a useful blog from NSHipster on available environment settings: http://nshipster.com/launch-arguments-and-environment-variables/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with XcodeColors. I ended up solving it with a simple script build phase. It checks to see if XcodeColors is installed or not and sets/adds a key to the Info.plist in the build. So create a new "Run Script Build Phase" and put this in there:

```
xcodeColorsDir="$USER_LIBRARY_DIR/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plugins/XcodeColors.xcplugin/"
xcodeColorsInstalled=0
if [ -d "$xcodeColorsDir" ]; then
    # Directory exists, therefore, XcodeColors is installed
    xcodeColorsInstalled=1
fi

infoPlistPath="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
existingValue=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :XcodeColorsInstalled" "$infoPlistPath")
if [ -z "$existingValue" ]; then
    # Key already exists so overwrite it
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :XcodeColorsInstalled bool $xcodeColorsInstalled" "$infoPlistPath"
else
    # Key doesn't exist yet
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :XcodeColorsInstalled $xcodeColorsInstalled" "$infoPlistPath"
fi
```

Then, you can access the Info.plist param during runtime with something like:

```
func isColorizedLoggingEnabled() -> Bool {
    if let colorizedLoggingEnabled = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["XcodeColorsInstalled"] as? Bool {
        return colorizedLoggingEnabled
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```